# Mock Entire Class including constructor, instance and static functions

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have yet to see any full answer/example for this. In my TypeScript project, I have a Class that has a constructor, a function, and a static function. All three are invoked in the code under test. I'd like to write a unit test using Jest that allows me to check the mocked constructor, mocked function, and mocked static function.

I typically use the mock factory approach for mocking Classes (like below); however, I cannot seem to get this to work.

```
// ClassA.ts
export class ClassA {
  constructor() {
    // construction logic
  }

  public async func1(x: int): Promise<void> {
    // func1 logic
  }

  static func2(x: string | number): x is string {
    // func2 logic
    let conditionIsMet: boolean;

    // conditionIsMet logic

    if (conditionIsMet) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}

// CodeUnderTest.ts
import { ClassA } from './ClassA';

export class ClassB {
  public async foo() {
    if (ClassA.func2('asdf')) {
      const a = new ClassA();
      await a.func1(45);
    }
  }
}

// UnitTest.ts
import { ClassB } from './ClassB';

// mock factory
const mockFunc1 = jest.fn();
const mockStaticFunc2 = jest.fn();
jest.mock('./ClassA', () => ({
  ClassA: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    func1: mockFunc1,
    func2: mockStaticFunc2, // <= this doesn't work
  }),
});

beforeAll(() => {
  mockStaticFunc2.mockReturnValue(true);
});
describe('when ClassB.foo() is called', () => {
  describe('when ClassA.func2 is given a string parameter', () => {
    it('then ClassA.func2 is invoked with expected parameters, ClassA is constructed, ClassA.func1 is invoked with expected parameters', () => {
      // arrange
      const clsB = new ClassB();

      // execute
      clsB.foo();

      // expect
      expect(mockStaticFunc2).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(mockStaticFunc2).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, 'asdf');
      expect(ClassA).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);  // constructor was mocked
      expect(mockFunc1).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(mockFunc1).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, 45);
    });
  });
});
```

Are there any **complete** examples that illustrates how I can propertly mock all three (ClassA construtor, ClassA.func1 instance function, and ClassA.func2 static function)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mock the static method `func2` correctly. The static methods are accessed on the class itself. Besides, take a look [es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock)

Here is an example:

`ClassA.ts`:

```
export class ClassA {
  constructor() {}
  public async func1(x: number): Promise<string> {
    return 'real value';
  }
  static func2(x: string | number) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

`ClassB.ts`:

```
import { ClassA } from './ClassA';

export class ClassB {
  public async foo() {
    if (ClassA.func2('asdf')) {
      const a = new ClassA();
      const r = await a.func1(45);
      console.log(" ~ file: ClassB.ts:8 ~ ClassB ~ foo ~ r:", r)
    }
  }
}
```

`ClassB.test.ts`:

```
import { ClassB } from './ClassB';
import { ClassA } from './ClassA';

// Mock each methods manually
// jest.mock('./ClassA', () => {
//   const MockClassA = jest.fn(function () {
//     this.func1 = jest.fn()
//   });
//   (MockClassA as any).func2 = jest.fn();
//   return {
//     ClassA: MockClassA,
//   };
// });

// or, let jest create mocks for you
jest.mock('./ClassA');

describe('when ClassB.foo() is called', () => {
  describe('when ClassA.func2 is given a string parameter', () => {
    it('then ClassA.func2 is invoked with expected parameters, ClassA is constructed, ClassA.func1 is invoked with expected parameters', async () => {
      expect(jest.isMockFunction(ClassA)).toBe(true);
      expect(jest.isMockFunction(ClassA.func2)).toBe(true);
      expect(jest.isMockFunction(ClassA.prototype.func1)).toBe(true);
      const ClassAMocked = jest.mocked(ClassA);

      // arrange
      const clsB = new ClassB();
      jest.mocked(ClassA.func2).mockReturnValueOnce(true);
      jest.mocked(ClassA.prototype.func1).mockResolvedValueOnce('fake value');

      // execute
      await clsB.foo();

      // expect
      const classAInstance = ClassAMocked.mock.instances[0];
      expect(jest.isMockFunction(classAInstance.func1)).toBe(true);
      expect(ClassAMocked.func2).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, 'asdf');
      expect(ClassAMocked).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(classAInstance.func1).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, 45);
    });
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
  console.log
     ~ file: ClassB.ts:8 ~ ClassB ~ foo ~ r: fake value

      at ClassB.log (stackoverflow/77559902/ClassB.ts:8:15)

 PASS  stackoverflow/77559902/ClassB.test.ts
  when ClassB.foo() is called
    when ClassA.func2 is given a string parameter
      ✓ then ClassA.func2 is invoked with expected parameters, ClassA is constructed, ClassA.func1 is invoked with expected parameters (11 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.508 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

package versions:

```json
"jest": "^29.7.0"
```

Comment: This is an intersting example, thank you! I must ask, with your example, how can I setup a mock resolved value for the async ClassA.func1 instance method prior to executing clsB.foo()? Is there a way I can set it up so that all instances ever constructued have a mocked func1 method that I can control (via mockResolvedValue) as well as check with expect(mockFunc1).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(...)?

Comment: @jad45 You can do `ClassA.prototype.func1.mockResolvedValue()`, updated answer.